# Version missing in dependencies for spring parent

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have the following pom.xml:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth-service</name>
    <description>Authorization service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        For Eureka Client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I keep getting error about missing version.

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar is
>   missing. @ line 34, column 21 [ERROR]
>   'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar
>   is missing. @ line 56, column 21

Isn't it that spring parent should provide those versions?

How to provide the right versions and why the spring boot-parrent is not providing one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see you have `spring.cloud.version` but there is no such `dependencyManagement` import like below (which will import all versions for child dependencies). Kindly note that `<spring-cloud-netflix.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-netflix.version>` is available in this spring-cloud-dependencies pom [file](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Greenwich.SR1/pom).

The `spring-boot-starter-parent` will not have any dependencies for `org.springframework.cloud` group.

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth-service</name>
    <description>Authorization service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        For Eureka Client-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: so why can't I just simply use `spring-cloud-dependencies` as a regular dependency ? Why do I need this `dependencyManagement` anyway?

Comment: it's the feature in maven, you can take a look on this docs https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies

Comment: Ok I still have this second issue with `spring-security-oauth2` how to handle this?

Comment: `spring-security-oauth2` is not part of spring-boot or spring cloud (i.e group name is `org.springframework.security.oauth`, so you need to add version manually

Comment: Ok but shall I place the deps in `dependencyManagement` as discribed in your link  or under regular `dependencies` section?

Comment: treat the dependencyManagement as meta data, note that there is `<type>pom</type>` and `<scope>import</scope>`. So if the artifact is just pom file, then put it under `dependencyManagement`, meanwhile if it's normal jar, just put in `dependencies`

Comment: ok, can you provide working pom and write answer so that I can accept is?

Comment: Whay can't I simply put into `dependencyManagement` this:
`<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>` and then simply put the `spring-security-oauth2` dependency without version as in case of `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192831/discussion-between-apolozeus-and-mcs).