# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.reactive.ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to setup spring cloud config client here's my pom dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=test-ms
server.port=4532
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.username=root
spring.cloud.config.password=s3cr3t
```

I got this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.reactive.ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:327)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:483)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:403)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:288)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:79)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
```

...

How can I fix this? I googled and found that SimpleReactiveDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java is part of spring-cloud-commons since 2.2.0 which is only RC now: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/reactive/SimpleReactiveDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java
When I added spring-cloud-commons 2.2.0 it worked but is the any way to get this working without using RC?

I use spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-config 2.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: Errors like these generally come from mixing incompatible versions of frameworks.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edit post and added version details.

Comment: Afaik there is no final Spring Cloud version for Spring Boot 2.2 yet. The Hoxton release train is for Spring Boot 2.2. So either use the Hoxton versions and for the time being use a RC version (it is RC2 so RELEASE should be around the corner). Or move the Spring Boot 2.1 with Spring Cloud Greenwich release (SR4) which are compatible. Also please use the Spring Cloud BOM and not individual starters/jars with versions as that will lead to breakage somewhere .

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to spring (coming from Front-End/JavaScript background) so a lot is weird and over-complicated to me in the Java world.

I did some digging and found some links that may help explain in detail:

- https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__quick_start.html
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies
- [Version missing in dependencies for spring parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981220/version-missing-in-dependencies-for-spring-parent)

Basically (how i understand it; i could be wrong), spring cloud works ON TOP of spring boot; it isn't a regular dependency/part of the spring boot group/project. So basically, it needs (what is called) Dependency Management.

Add this to your pom.xml (THIS worked for me):

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

That is for setting the project as the parent app. If that does not work, then try this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

In that approach, i'm GUESSING that this is for deciding what version to use for the spring cloud dependencies in the pom. For this one, make sure that the `properties` element has a spring cloud version added (that is what the `<version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>` is going to refer to):

```xml
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Again, the first approach worked for me. See the links for more info. Finding more info and docs on this was harder than i thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you facing the problem then add this to your pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

and add the dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and mention the below two annotations in main application class :

> @EnableDiscoveryClient @EnableEurekaClient